# How get a GitHub repository files Commit by Commit?

Tags: git, github, repository, commit, checkout

I  recently learning a course and he has put files on GitHub repo! But I need to have all files step by step or in this course, commit by commit ! I want to change some part of codes so it's not good for me to `git checkout` every time! Thanks.

Comment: Just `git clone` repository, then `git checkout` your own branch and work on it. Or, you can fork repo , if it is hosted on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

> But I need to have all files step by step or in this course, commit by commit !

#### Check files commit by commit

Prepare a list of all commit SHAs from the beginging of the development. Use `git checkout <commit-SHA>` to check the files at a specific commit.

#### Continue development with your changes

> I want to change some part of codes so it's not good for me to git checkout every time!

Do you have a plan to continue and finish the project with your changes starting from a specific commit/branch in the repo from original author?

You can create your own branch from a specific commit in original repository

```
git branch <your-branch-name> <SHA-of-commit-from-which-you-want-to-start>
git checkout <your-branch-name>
```

After you are done with your changes, if you want to include a commit from original authour, you can cherry-pick them.

```
git cherry-pic <SHA-of-the-commit-you-want-to-include>
```

#### Be careful to handle any merge conflict.

Comment: hey Man, thank you but I just want to check codes and write some comments to save my notes! I don;t want write any code and I want to have every change in commits in a separate file! I think I have to checkout them one by one and copy them to another specified folder! :(

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repository.

git clone repourl